# How can the downstream propagation of every KTable change be enforced?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In the following stream the aggregate changes frequently ie. within milliseconds new events will be added. Once it arrives at the peek, always the whole aggregate with several elements will be logged. But what I need is the propagation of the aggregate after every single change. However, even if I set `commit.interval.ms: 0` still only the state with several/all elements will be forwarded.

```kotlin
            mangelImporte
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(
                    { MangelImportAggregat() },
                    { _, mangelImportEvent, aggregat -> aggregat + mangelImportEvent }
                )
                .leftJoin(
                    mangelTable,
                    { it.current?.metaInfo?.correlationId?.toString() },
                    { mangelImportAggregat, mangelEvent ->
                        mangelEvent?.let {
                            mangelImportAggregat.removeFirst()
                        } ?: mangelImportAggregat
                    },
                    Materialized.`as`<MangelImportKey, MangelImportAggregat, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>
                        (MangelImportJoinStore.NAME).withCachingDisabled()
                )
                .toStream()
                .process(ProcessorSupplier { EventTypeHeaderProcessor() })
                .peek { key, value -> logger().info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< $key - $value") }
```